# Pull Json Compare against PHP and Insert

Tags: php, html, json, html-table, compare

After receiving help below @rx2347 everything is working the way it should except one things. I have edited my question to better explain the issue.

I have an json array and I am pulling certain data such as 'id' and 'start' start displays a date and time together. I am comparing the date with the calendars date and trying to insert the correct time in the correct date. Kind of like a matching game.

Currently everything works however inserting is only inserting the very last value in the array and I need it to insert every value. Getting stuck below is what I have now after the help from @rx2347

```
<?php
$url = 'JSON ARRAY';
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$array = json_decode($data, true);
foreach($array as $your_json_date) {
//convert date and time
$your_date = strftime("%G%m%d", strtotime($your_json_date["start"]));
$your_time = strftime("%I:%M %P",strtotime($your_json_date["start"]));
$your_id = $your_json_date["id"];
$result = '<a href="MY URL'.$your_id .'">'.$your_time.'</a>';
}
$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
<th><strong>M</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>W</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>F</strong></th>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
  // compare your date and calendar date
  $thisdate = strftime("%G%m%d",strtotime($cMonth."/".($i - $startday + 1)."/".$cYear));
  if($your_date == $thisdate) $time = $result; else $time = "";
    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";
    else {
      echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>";

        echo ($i - $startday + 1);
        //output time
        echo "<br><b>".$time."</b>";

      echo "</td>";
    }
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you using Composer? If so, install Carbon. `composer require nesbot/carbon`

Comment: No not using Composer

Answer (score 1):

So, all you need to know is how to compare those two dates, right?

First: Convert both dates to the same format using [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and [strftime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php)

```
$date = "05/02/2020 1:00 PM";
echo strftime("%G%m%d",strtotime($date));
```

This will convert your JSON date to "20200502", no matter what time. Do the same with your PHP date from your calendar and check if they are equal. Done.

I hope I understood you correctly.

This is the altered code:

```
<?php
//your json date
$your_json_date = "05/02/2020 1:00 PM";
//convert date and time
$your_date = strftime("%G%m%d", strtotime($your_json_date));
$your_time = strftime("%I:%M %P",strtotime($your_json_date));

$monthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["month"])) $_REQUEST["month"] = date("n");
if (!isset($_REQUEST["year"])) $_REQUEST["year"] = date("Y");
$cMonth = $_REQUEST["month"];
$cYear = $_REQUEST["year"];
$prev_year = $cYear;
$next_year = $cYear;
$prev_month = $cMonth-1;
$next_month = $cMonth+1;
if ($prev_month == 0 ) {
    $prev_month = 12;
    $prev_year = $cYear - 1;
}
if ($next_month == 13 ) {
    $next_month = 1;
    $next_year = $cYear + 1;
}
?>
<table width="200">
<tr align="center">
<td bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td width="50%" align="left"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $prev_month . "&year=" . $prev_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Previous</a></td>
<td width="50%" align="right"><a href="<?php echo "?month=". $next_month . "&year=" . $next_year; ?>" style="color:#FFFFFF">Next</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<tr align="center">
<td colspan="7" bgcolor="#999999" style="color:#FFFFFF"><strong><?php echo $monthNames[$cMonth-1].' '.$cYear; ?></strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
<th><strong>M</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>W</strong></th>
<th><strong>T</strong></th>
<th><strong>F</strong></th>
<th><strong>S</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php
$timestamp = mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,1,$cYear);
$maxday = date("t",$timestamp);
$thismonth = getdate ($timestamp);
$startday = $thismonth['wday'];
for ($i=0; $i<($maxday+$startday); $i++) {
  // compare your date and calendar date
  $thisdate = strftime("%G%m%d",strtotime($cMonth."/".($i - $startday + 1)."/".$cYear));
  if($your_date == $thisdate) $time = $your_time; else $time = "";

    if(($i % 7) == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    if($i < $startday) echo "<td></td>";
    else {
      echo "<td align='center' valign='middle' height='20px'>";
        echo ($i - $startday + 1);
        //output time
        echo "<br><b>".$time."</b>";
      echo "</td>";
    }
    if(($i % 7) == 6 ) echo "</tr>";



}
?>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Check the linked PHP docs for further changes.

Comment: This is kind of and almost exactly what I am trying do, Just have to figure out how to get the array of all of the dates and times in the json to line up with the correct dates on the calendar as well as the id and that is where I am stuck. Converting both dates is in the correct direction. Hard part for me is doing the array of all the dates and including the id.

Comment: Depending on the amount of data this could be a good usecase for a database. I find handling json files in php always kind of painful, especially for something like this where you have to actually find stuff. Or, if thats not an option: Why use PHP at all for this? This could be so much easier if you'd stick to js and html, the calendar logic really is the same. Just sayin. Good luck!

Comment: I can not use anything other than php and json on the server I have. but lets say I had `$your_json_date = array("05/02/2020 1:00 PM", "05/02/2020 3:00 PM", "05/03/2020 1:00 PM", "05/02/2020 3:00 PM", "05/03/2020 5:00 PM");` as well as another `$your_json_id = array("145", "146", "147", "148", "149");` I would need to be able to compare and then insert each from the array in the correct dated boxes in the calendar including the id that it belongs to in the json.

Comment: this should at least be the same array, so you don't ever loose or mixup the relationship between ids and dates: array("145"=>"05/02/2020 1:00 PM","146"=>"05/02/2020 3:00 PM"). have a look at associative arrays: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_associative.asp - I would structure this even further, so you can have a function which is given a specific date and then returns an array with all the times and ids for this date at once.

Comment: To be honest it is the same array I just wrote that out as an example. It is more like this in the json `{"id":"165","start":"05\/02\/2020 1:00 PM"},{"id":"166","start":"05\/03\/2020 1:00 PM"},{"id":"167","start":"05\/03\/2020 3:00 PM"}` What is funny is I knew you were going to say that and I was typing this out as you replied lol

Comment: Edited original question, Got everything going correctly but for some reason I can not figure out why the array is only inputting the last result only.

Comment: because while looping through your json data at each iteration of your foreach loop $your_date is set to a new value. so after the last foreach loop is finished, $your_date only contains the last date. as said earlier, you really want to build a function which you can call from inside the calendar loop which then outputs the time for the given date. check [array_filter](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_filter.asp) and [array_search](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_search.asp) to get you started.

Comment: I quickly wrote this up for you, its very simplified. Obviously you need to have a different array and a very different function to find your data for any given date in the array you setup, but this is the concept: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd64972d2d4ec2593256ede62330f446ac0aa19f hope this helps.

Comment: Yea that confuses me, Been about 7 years since I messed with PHP, Trying to brush up on it and learn. Have no idea where too start with building a function for this or where it would be used.

Comment: Sorry, but I really can't make this any easier and I can't code the whole thing for you. Maybe start with the basics then, whats a variable, whats an array, whats a loop, etc. its all out there! https://www.w3schools.com/php/